# How to correctly enable Imagick in PHP-FPM on Ubuntu 20.04 and Apache

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, imagemagick

I have PHP-FPM setup on my Ubuntu 20.04 server and have installed Imagick, but I cannot get it to be recognized by PHP 7.4. I tried following these steps, but step one returns the following error in Terminal.

```
-bash: /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini: Permission denied
```

1. sudo echo extension=imagick.so > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini
2. sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
3. sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini

The soft links worked correctly as I can see the files in each respective directory.

Is this just a permission issue or is there something else I need to complete to get this working? The permissions on the imagick.ini file are below.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 60 Mar  2  2020 /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini
```

PHP info shows **/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini** as being parsed, but not loaded like the GD library.

**PHP 8.0.8 is the version that is returned when using php -v**

Comment: First you need to decide if you're going to be using PHP 7.4 or 8.0. Trying to have both installed at once, as you have done, will only lead to confusion and breakage. Delete one or the other.